# Why my Sum result in SQLite is wrong?

Tags: sqlite

Why my following SQL query

```
Insert Into Test (ItemQty) VALUES (1.445);
Insert Into Test (ItemQty) VALUES (0.000000000000001);

Select Sum(ItemQty) from Test;
```

produces `1.445` as result and not `1.445000000000001` ?
What am i missing here?

Comment: You need to understand more about how computers and databases represent numbers.  First, understand the type of `ItemQty` and then do research on fixed- or floating- point values.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite Version 3 REAL values are stored as '8-byte IEEE floating point numbers' (*see* https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). These values allow for just less than 16 decimal digits (*see* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Basic_and_interchange_formats). However, the length of the constant 1.445000000000001 is 17, which is (just) beyond the capability of this format.

In fact, when I recreated your example but instead inserted the second value with one less zero after the decimal point I received the result 1.44500000000001.

Because that's only 16 digits long.